# Aggregation stats on Dynamodb Table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, bigdata, amazon-kinesis

I have a DynamoDB table that receives ~15M browsing records per day like:

```
{"domain": "google.com", "url": "https://google.com/search?q=test1", "user_id": 10, "action": "allowed"}
{"domain": "google.com", "url": "https://google.com/search?q=test2", "user_id": 10, "action": "allowed"}
{"domain": "facebook.com", "url": "https://www.facebook.com/feed", "user_id": 10, "action": "blocked"}
```

The history of individual records isn't that important, there's a TTL for 30 days to keep them. 
What I'm trying to think through is the best way to aggregate the the top domains for both `allowed` and `blocked`.

If it was basic counts per day, I could create a unique partition key for day and count and increment:

```
User-10-Totals, "2019-11-16", { "count": 2 }
```

But the trouble is each domain would have their own counts and there could be thousands of unique domains per day along with their counts.

I ultimately want to have a top 10 domains for a time period that's configurable.

```
Allowed for the last 30 days:
 1. google.com
 2. other.com
 ...

Blocked for the last 30 days:
 1. facebook.com
 2. other2.com
 ...
```

Is there a good way to store this without having to sift through potentially thousands of records and group on the client?

Comment: What sort of latency is acceptable when you’re looking up the top domains?

Comment: Within a couple hours feels reasonable. If the trade-off to wait longer is significantly simpler or less expensive, than it's worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Using Global Secondary Indexes for Materialized Aggregation Queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-gsi-aggregation.html)

You seem to have a textbook use-case for Streams + lambda function to calculate and update the aggregate counts.

If I recall correctly, the AWS reInvent video [Advanced Design Patterns for Amazon DynamoDB](https://youtu.be/jzeKPKpucS0) goes into some more detail including the "Top 10" functionality.

Comment: Good point. I've been reading many of those articles. I think the part that is getting me is there's an additional dimension beside the day and subject. For instance, it's user, day, and domain. Using my data, the examples are on 2 dimensions (e.g. counts of user and day). I thought about creating a record with a composite sort key with the domain, but then I'm left with potentially hundreds of records per day and still have to do the aggregation in the client, unless there's an additional aggregation step at the end of the day.